# Is using websockets a good idea for IPC?

Tags: python, node.js, websocket, ipc

I have a "main" process and a few "worker" processes between which I want to pass some messages. The messages could be binary blobs but has a fixed size for each. I want an abstraction which will neatly buffer and separate out each message for me. I don't want to invent my own protocol on top of TCP, and I can't find any simple+lightweight solution that is portable across languages. (As of now, the "main" process is a Node.js server, and the "worker" processes are planned to be in Python.)

Answer (score 4):

The question is purely opinion based but I will give it a shot anyway:

WebSocket is an overkill imo. First of all in order to make WebSockets work you have to implement HTTP (or at least some basic form of it) to do the handshake. If you do that then it is better to stick to "normal" HTTP unless there's a reason for full-duplex communication. There are lots of tools everywhere to handle HTTP over (unix domain) sockets.

But this might be an overkill as well. If you have workers then I suppose performance matters. The easiest and (probably) most efficient solution is a following protocol: each message starts with 1-8 (pick a number) bytes which determine the size of the following content. The content is anything you want, e.g. protobuf message. For example if you want to send `foo`, then you send `0x03 0x00 0x66 0x6f 0x6f`. First two bytes correspond to the size of the content (being `3`) and then 3 bytes correspond to `foo`.

Comment: The problem with the protocol you suggested (that I also thought of) is that if one of the end-points is buggy and sends a larger or smaller message than what it says, how would I detect the error, recover and then process the next message? I'm wondering if there're any good protocols that are written for this simple purpose. (May be it deserves a question of its own.)

Comment: Also, I thought WebSockets had less overhead than HTTP. Am I wrong? (Although I do need sort of full duplex communication, and not a simple request-response that I'm currently planning.)

Comment: @John For messages bigger then expected you can add a checksum (as a part of the message, say 8 bytes after the "size header") for validation. For messages smaller then expected you need a timeout (note that you can't assume that you received everything, it may be a communication lag). Also note that WebSockets don't save you from these problems (a buggy endpoint may still send a partial content wrapped in a proper websocket frame).

Comment: As for overhead: WebSockets may potentially have a bigger overhead due to frame masking. For small messages they are indeed more efficient then HTTP. For full duplex communication I would go with a custom protocol.

Comment: And that's why I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel. I can't understand why there's no standard simple library but there's a couple of "standard" and well-tested complex libraries. Do you have an opinion about nanomsg in this case?

Comment: @John it's not about reinventing. Note that neither HTTP nor WebSockets (nor any known to me general purpose protocol) use checksums. If you need integrity checks then you will probably have to implement your own checksums anyway. Depending on your needs you may reuse some existing protocol like torrent.

Comment: I've never heard about nanomsg. Sounds interesting.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need a message broker of some sort.

Your requirement for “buffering” would exclude, for example, ZeroMQ (which is ideal for inter-process communication, but has no built-in message persistence).

This leaves you with options such as RabbitMQ or SQS if you happen to be on AWS. You might also look at Kafka (Kinesis on AWS). These services all offer “buffering” of messages, with RabbitMQ offering the greatest range of configurations, but probably the greatest implementation hurdle.

Another option would be to use Redis as a simple messaging service.

There are a number options, all of which suit different use-cases and environments. I should add though that “simple and lightweight” doesn’t really fit with any solution other than - perhaps - ZeroMQ

Comment: I'm trying to avoid external brokers for simple messaging. I considered nanomsg (successor of 0MQ), but it felt like an overkill to me since there are only a handful of workers such that scalability is not an issue.

Comment: Honestly, I would describe inter-process communication as a potential minefield (particularly with Python on one or both ends). I’m obviously slightly behind the curve on ZeroMQ / nanomsg, but I would definitely prefer to go that route: at least you know the communication/protocol can be relied upon.